# Word cloud generated from URLs in pandas df - one word cloud for 220 articles instead of one word cloud per article

Tags: python, pandas, flask, beautifulsoup, word-cloud

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Title                      Source       Date              Link
    'Corona news'              NY Times     01-06-2020        nyt.com/corona_news
220 rows × 4 columns
```

So I have 220 links to news articles in this df which I want to use to make a wordcloud out of and host it through flask.

I have the following code which remodeled to use it to make wordclouds out of the df links.

main.py

```
import base64
import feedparser
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template 

app = Flask(__name__)

BBC_FEED = pd.read_excel('All_news_corona.xlsx')
LIMIT = 20

class Article:
    def __init__(self, url, image):
        self.url = url
        self.image = image

@app.route("/")
def home():
    # feed = feedparser.parse(BBC_FEED)
    articles = []

    for article in BBC_FEED['Link'][:LIMIT]:
        print(article)
        text = parse_article(article)
        cloud = get_wordcloud(text)
        articles.append(Article(article, cloud))
    return render_template('home.html', articles=articles)

def parse_article(article_url):
    print("Downloading {}".format(article_url))
    r = requests.get(article_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    ps = soup.find_all('p')
    text = "\n".join(p.get_text() for p in ps)
    return text

def get_wordcloud(text):
    pil_img = WordCloud().generate(text=text).to_image()
    img = io.BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(img, "PNG")
    img.seek(0)
    img_b64 = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    return img_b64

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run('127.0.0.1')
```

home.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>News in WordClouds | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
      body {padding: 20px;}
      img{padding: 5px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>News Word Clouds</h1>
      <p>Too busy to click on each news article to see what it's about? Below you can see all the articles from the BBC front page, displayed as word clouds. If you want to read more about any particular article, just click on the wordcloud to go to the original article</p>
      {% for article in articles %}
        <a href="{{article.url}}"><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{article.image}}"></a>
      {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

However, instead of using it to make one wordcloud per article, I want to use it to make one wordcloud, which takes input from all the articles. Does anyone have a quick fix?

Comment: It's a bit rude to say "quick fix needed"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all parsed texts into a single string, then pass that to your wordcloud function:

```
all_texts = []

for article in BBC_FEED['Link'][:LIMIT]:
    all_texts.append(parse_article(article))

cloud = get_wordcloud(" ".join(all_texts))
articles.append(Article(url=None, image=cloud))  # no URL for the "meta-article"
return render_template('home.html', articles=articles)
```